# Netlogo: move turtles to different agent sets

Tags: list, variables, netlogo, agent

I'm trying to simulate a car production factory and trying to keep separate lists of turtles who are on jobs and who are not on jobs.

I have a turtles-own variable: `is-on-job?`

I want to have a agent set of turtles not on jobs `not-working-turtles`

I want to have a agent set of turtles on jobs `working-turtles`

Whenever a turtle is on a job, is there a way to remove that specific turtle from the `not-working-turtles` agentset and add it to the `working-turtles` agentset?

Also on a different topic, is there a way to sort turtles based on distance to a specific patch and then if the closest turtle is on a job then go to the second turtle and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your two agentsets as:

```
let not-working-turtles turtles with [not is-on-job?]
let working-turtles turtles with [is-on-job?]
```

To move a turtle from one to the other, you will need code along the lines of:

```
to make-me-work
  let free one-of not-working-turtles
  ask free
  [ set is-on-job? true
    set not-working-turtles other not-working-turtles
  ]
  set working-turtles (turtle-set working-turtles free)
end
```

Here I used the very convenient `other` primitive to remove the turtle doing the asking. You are more likely to want to do this as a procedure that takes arguments and pass the turtle to the procedure rather than randomly select one within the procedure, but the code would be similar.

On your question about choosing the closest, you don't need to sort. Instead, look at `min-one-of` in the NetLogo dictionary. If you can't work it out, please do a new question (StackOverflow should be only one question per question) with the relevant code.